# How to select only one element from several elements in React (React,typescript)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

In this project, React, TypeScript and ant design are used. In a part of the project, only one box out of three boxes should be selected. I have used "useState" and toggle, but when I select one, they are all selected together when only one should be selected. I am using React version 18.2.0
I would be grateful if you could guide me.

```css
allBox{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 700px
}
.box{
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    background: green;
    color:blue;
}

.box.active{
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { useState } from "react";
function MyBox() {
  const boxes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "1",
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      type: "2",
    },

    {
      id: 3,
      type: "3",
    },
  ];

  const [boxSelect, setBoxSelect] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    setBoxSelect(!boxSelect);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='allBox'>
        {boxes.map((box) => {
          return (
            <div className={`${box} ${boxSelect && 'active'}`} key={box.id} onClick={handleSelect}>
              
              <p>{box.type}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyBox;
```

Comment: You have a `handleSelect()`but it is never called. You also have a `setGenderSelect()` but useState is never declared. You have a declared a useState for `boxSelect`, bit its never called. Can you please clean up your code a bit so its easier to understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry. You are right

Answer (score 0):

It's because all your boxes share the same `const [boxSelect, setBoxSelect] = useState(false);` so if you click on one of them, they will all be selected.

You have two solutions:

- create a children component with only:

```
function mySubBox(box) {
  const [boxSelect, setBoxSelect] = useState(false);

  const handleSelect = () => {
    setBoxSelect(!boxSelect);
  };

  return (
      <div className={`${box} ${boxSelect && 'active'}`} key={box.id} onClick={handleSelect}>
         <p>{box.type}</p>
      </div>
  );
}
```

And the parent loops through it:

```
{boxes.map((box, i) => <mySubBox box={box} key={i}/>)}
```

- another solution would be to keep only one component and store the selected boxes in an array: if I click on the 2nd box, my selected array is [2], and you add/remove the item inside the array.